# geom_rect gives empty plot with no rectangle

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I would like to get a rectangle box between every point of dawn and dusk. I don't understand why the code below is not giving the desired result

```
dawn = seq(200, 210, by =  0.5)
dusk = seq(200.5, 210.5, by = 0.5)
night = data.frame("dusk" = dusk, "dawn" = dawn)


ggplot()+
  geom_rect(data = night, aes(xmin = dawn , xmax = dusk ,
                              ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
 fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5, colour = NA)
```

[image]
I couldnt see the filled rectangle.

Comment: `Inf` isn't possible to draw... Specify exact values and maybe use high values for `min/ymax` and define axis limits...

Comment: ya. you are correct! it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could define the coordinate system with limits...

```
ggplot()+
    geom_rect(data = night, aes(xmin = dawn , xmax = dusk ,
                                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5, colour = NA) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.2,0.8))
```

In this way it works with `Inf` as well.

Comment: That's a good idea. But would this work if we have facets with different scales of y?

Comment: Not sure at the moment... Give it a try, I think the `coord_cartesian` is independent from the facets... Use `sclaes='free_y'` should work, but not sure...
U didn't asked for it in the first place :-D

Comment: without a y - what are those different scales for y for :D

Answer (score 2):

You need a y aesthetic. What do you want to plot anyways??

```r
library(ggplot2)
dawn = seq(200, 210, by =  0.5)
dusk = seq(200.5, 210.5, by = 0.5)
night = data.frame("dusk" = dusk, "dawn" = dawn, y = 1)


ggplot(night, aes(dawn, y))+
  geom_rect(data = night, aes(xmin = dawn , xmax = dusk ,
                              ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5, colour = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>